# My wheel tilts to the left (to the disc side) any solution

Tags: wheels, disc-brake, front

My front tire tilts to the left when I brake hard when speeding on my bicycle. I tried almost everything to get it fixed but no luck. Can you guys tell me the reason for that? If you know how to fix it please tell me.

Comment: is it tightly fastened to the fork?

Comment: If spoke tension is low, the wheel can experience deflection under braking.

Answer (score 1):

It is a normal effect with disc brakes, the major reason why most motorbikes have left and right  discs at the front. Braking on the left side only will cause a slight deformation of the left leg of the fork, pushing it backwards. The wheel follows.

I'd guess you have quick releases on your bike. If you do, try to tighten it a bit more. Through axles have been introduced to help better secure the wheel in the drop outs but also to stabilize the fork.

Answer (score 1):

First check that all the spokes from the front wheel have the proper tension. As the disc brake is on the left side of the wheel, the force applied on it when braking deforms it and tilt it a little bit. Is a common effect but shouldn't be so important or dangerous. However if the spokes have not the adequate tension, it could be increase this feeling. Check the spokes first.

Comment: The force from braking tightens leading spokes and loosens trailing ones, so the net effect evens out. Forks with disc on one side, however, do deform on braking.